# How to convert UIImagePicker image into a byte array objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, arrays, uiimagepickercontroller

I am selecting a `UIImage`from image picker. Then I want to pass my selected image as a byte array to the server. so in this delegate I am getting the path of my selected image like this.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info

filePath=info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
```

Then convert into a byte array I do like this.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:filePath];
NSUInteger len = [data length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);
NSLog(@"----BITE DATA----%@",byteData);
```

but this `data` always get nil. why is that? Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: see my updated code ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plz use this

```
  UIImage *Image = (UIImage*)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(Image, 1); //1 it represents the quality of the image.
        NSLog(@"Size of Image(bytes):%d",[imgData length]);
```

Answer (score 1):

inside method `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` get image using below code.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage)];
    NSLog(@"image string : %@",info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]);

    // save using nsuserdefaults or any other your local database
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageData forKey:@"imageData"];
}
```

Now show it to anywhere using below code.

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"imageData"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
self.imageView.image = image;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

  UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];


  NSData* imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0);

    // Add selected imageData in Array and pass imageData to server
     [imageDataArray addObject:imageData];


}
```